# I'm having an issue displaying the card rate according to the selected card category

Tags: python, django

Please, I need help with my Django project.
I'm having an issue displaying the card rate according to the selected card category.
I have been having this Issue for a while now please I need help.

[image: Here is my front-end]

Here is my my view:

```
 @login_required(login_url='/Authentication/login')
    def giftcard(request):
        giftcards = Giftcard.objects.filter(publish=True)
    
        context = {
            'giftcards': giftcards,
            'categories': categories,
        }
        return render(request, 'dashboard/giftcard.html', context)
```

Here is my models and I link them using ForeignKey:

```
class Giftcard(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
card_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Giftcard/', blank=False)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Giftcard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class CardRate(models.Model):
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    card_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is my template, i think am writing the wrong code here:

```
{% for giftcard in giftcards %}
          <!-- Card -->

            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center  justify-content-center">
              <div class="gift__card-modal-container py-5">
                <div class="card__container">
                  <div class="gift__card-overlay"></div>
                  <div class="container-fluid bg-light  gift__card-modal shadow-lg">
                    <div class="pop p-5">
                      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 p-0 m-0">
                          <img class="img-fluid gift__card-img" style="width: 40rem;" src="{{ giftcard.card_image.url }}">
                          <p class="text-muted">Select the card category and the amount.</p>
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 card-details">
                          <form class="card-form">
                            <div class="form-group py-2">
                              <label for="card-category">Card category</label>
            
                              <select id="category" class="form-select py-2" aria-label="Default select example">
                                {% for spec in giftcard.category_set.all %}
                                <option value="{{ spec.category }}">{{ spec.category }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                              </select>
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="form-group py-2">
                              <label for="Amount">Amount</label>
                              <div class="d-flex align-items-center amount">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Please enter amount">
                                <span class="">#100,000</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="form-group py-3">
                              {% for spec in giftcard.category_set.all %}
                              <label for="rate">Current rate - {{ spec.rate }}</label>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="border-none pt-2 pl-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                              <button type="button" class="btn  process-card-btn">Proceed</button>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        </div>
            
                      </div>
                    </div>
            
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the foreign key in the gift card class not in the category, because each card has a category and each category has one or many cards, so you need to do that in your models.py :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    

class Giftcard(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
     card_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Giftcard/', blank=False)
     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, from what am doing a card can have multi categories  and a category can only have one card, that's why i set my models the way it is

Comment: Ok, i see, so in your view.py you are passing as a context "categories" without giving it  value before

Comment: please how am I suppose to write the code?

Comment: am having error because giftcard has field called category
"Function" has no attribute categories

Comment: Did you try what i proposed in the answer below ? add the "related_name" to card field in Category class and edit your giftcard function in view.py also edit your html template file.

Comment: yes sir, i updated everything

Comment: Okay you said that giftcard has field called category but i don't see that in your code

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you can try this add related_name to your card field :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Giftcard, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                           related_name="categories")
```

and in your view :

```
@login_required(login_url='/Authentication/login')
    def giftcard(request):
        giftcards = Giftcard.objects.filter(publish=True)
        categories = giftcards.categories.all()

    
        context = {
            'giftcards': giftcards,
            'categories': categories,
        }
        return render(request, 'dashboard/giftcard.html', context)
```

In your html page :

```
{% for giftcard in giftcards %}
          <!-- Card -->

            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center  justify-content-center">
              <div class="gift__card-modal-container py-5">
                <div class="card__container">
                  <div class="gift__card-overlay"></div>
                  <div class="container-fluid bg-light  gift__card-modal shadow-lg">
                    <div class="pop p-5">
                      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 p-0 m-0">
                          <img class="img-fluid gift__card-img" style="width: 40rem;" src="{{ giftcard.card_image.url }}">
                          <p class="text-muted">Select the card category and the amount.</p>
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 card-details">
                          <form class="card-form">
                            <div class="form-group py-2">
                              <label for="card-category">Card category</label>
            
                              <select id="category" class="form-select py-2" aria-label="Default select example">
                                {% for spec in categories %}
                                <option value="{{ spec.category }}">{{ spec.category }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                              </select>
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="form-group py-2">
                              <label for="Amount">Amount</label>
                              <div class="d-flex align-items-center amount">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Please enter amount">
                                <span class="">#100,000</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="form-group py-3">
                              {% for spec in categories %}
                              <label for="rate">Current rate - {{ spec.rate }}</label>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="border-none pt-2 pl-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                              <button type="button" class="btn  process-card-btn">Proceed</button>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        </div>
            
                      </div>
                    </div>
            
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            {% endfor %}
```